# Android espresso test NavigationView

Tags: android, android-navigationview, android-espresso

I am writing some espressotests for an appplication I recently made.
I'm using a NavigationView inside a DrawerLayout as sliding menu.

I managed to open the drawer this way:

```
        onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).perform(open());
```

This works so now I am trying to perform a click on a menuitem in the NavigationView.

```
onView(withId(R.id.nav_register))..
```

can not find the view. I tried several things but I can't find a way to retrieve the menuitem view. This is the way the items are assigned in the code:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

and activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_register"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_register"
        android:title="Registreer" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_login"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_login"
        android:title="Log in" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_play"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_play"
        android:title="Speel sessie" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_logout"
        android:title="Log uit" />
</group>
```

I read something about NavigationViewMenuItem is a private member and not accessible. Can someone help me out?

Greets!
Shenno

Comment: It sounds like the id of the menu items is not the same as the views that are constructed for the menu.  Perhaps use a different matcher to find the view by its text rather than its id?

Comment: To help others that got here with problems to interact with drawer, to use ".perform(open)" you must add a dependency:
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.1'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the View representing the menu item doesn't know the id of the menu item in Android. As a result the method `withId()` doesn't work in Espresso with menu items specifically.
I suggest you use the `withText` method:

```
onView(withText("the item title")).
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to stick to ID then you can use :

```
onView(withId(R.id.nav_view)).perform(NavigationViewActions.navigateTo(R.id. nav_register));
```

Comment: NavigationViewActions is not included with Expresso
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp/todoapp/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/custom/action/NavigationViewActions.java

Comment: Please add
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2"